# getting weather results from json (kotlin android)

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm trying to get some results from json but i have a problem.When i have only this line of code it works and i can get the temperature

```
var main: TemperatureData? = null
```

but i want also to get more values from my json so i insert this line of code

```
var weather: WeatherDataJson? = null
```

When i'm adding the second line it doesn't fetch any data(it even stops fetching the var main:... data)

This is my weather data class

```
class WeatherData {
    var main: TemperatureData? = null
    var weather: WeatherDataJson? = null

}
```

here is my interface class

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("data/2.5/weather?q=Prague")
    fun getWeatherData(@Query("appid") appId: String)
            : Call<WeatherData>

}
```

My TemperatureData class

```
data class TemperatureData(var temp: String)
```

And my WeatherDataJson class

```
data class WeatherDataJson(var description:String)
```

In my mainclass i have a function to show the json into my screen but i can't load the "var weather..."
Here is the function

```
private fun getTemperatureData(repository: Repository) {
        repository.getApiInterface()
                .getWeatherData("4cf7f6610d941a1ca7583f50e7e41ba3")
                .enqueue(object : Callback<WeatherData> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherData>?, t: Throwable?) {
                        t?.printStackTrace()
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<WeatherData>?, response: Response<WeatherData>?) {
                        val weatherData: WeatherData? = response?.body()
                        weatherData?.let {
                            it.main?.let {
                                tempText.text = it.temp
                            }
                            it.weather?.let{
                                weatherTextFromApi.text=it.description
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
    }
```

On the **description** is says unresolved reference description

Comment: Could you please add json response which server returned

Comment: I'm sorry im new to this.What do you mean?

Comment: hmm. do you use openweathermap.org  api ?

Comment: Yes.this is the link 
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Prague&appid=4cf7f6610d941a1ca7583f50e7e41ba3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use openweathermap api declare those data classes

```
data class WeatherData(
    @SerializedName("coord") val coord: Coord,
    @SerializedName("weather") val weather: List<Weather>,
    @SerializedName("base") val base: String,
    @SerializedName("main") val main: TemperatureData,
    @SerializedName("visibility") val visibility: Int,
    @SerializedName("wind") val wind: Wind,
    @SerializedName("clouds") val clouds: Clouds,
    @SerializedName("dt") val dt: Int,
    @SerializedName("sys") val sys: Sys,
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("cod") val cod: Int
)

data class Sys(
    @SerializedName("type") val type: Int,
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("message") val message: Double,
    @SerializedName("country") val country: String,
    @SerializedName("sunrise") val sunrise: Int,
    @SerializedName("sunset") val sunset: Int
)

data class Coord(
    @SerializedName("lon") val lon: Double,
    @SerializedName("lat") val lat: Double
)

data class TemperatureData(
    @SerializedName("temp") val temp: Double,
    @SerializedName("pressure") val pressure: Int,
    @SerializedName("humidity") val humidity: Int,
    @SerializedName("temp_min") val tempMin: Double,
    @SerializedName("temp_max") val tempMax: Double
)

data class Weather(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("main") val main: String,
    @SerializedName("description") val description: String,
    @SerializedName("icon") val icon: String
)

data class Clouds(
    @SerializedName("all") val all: Int
)

data class Wind(
    @SerializedName("speed") val speed: Double,
    @SerializedName("deg") val deg: Int
)
```

if you goal is get description from weather all you need will be

```
weatherData.weather.firstOrNull()?. description ?: ""
```

For getting url of icon

It is  kind of tricky, you could get url from response but only url of icon.

```
val iconId = weatherData.weather.firstOrNull()?. description
val iconUrl = iconId?.let{"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${it}.png"} ?: ""
```

After that you should use Glide library or Picasso for loading imageUrl to ImageView

See more about Glide here https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Declare them and then do what?

Comment: Using WeatherData I provided you will have access to weather field as well

Comment: i'm so sorry for spamming but i'm so new to this i can't understand.I did what you told me 
[link](https://ibb.co/jbOVtK)
but i have this in my main function and i don't know how to retrieve description
[link](https://ibb.co/idJune)

Comment: Oh i found it!!I had to type this
                                weatherTextFromApi.text=weatherData.weather.firstOrNull()?. description ?: ""

thanks a lot i really appreciate!!!

Comment: One more thing Alexander...If i want to get the icon from the weather what should i type?

Comment: Hey Alexander!i have one question please.how did you do all these "serializedname" stuff? you do it one by one or you found a way to convert json into this?

Comment: Hi! There are a lot of different tools, online and android studio plugin, just google 'json to kotlin data class'

Answer (score 0):

The server response from OpenWeatherMap is returning a JSON array, not a JSON object, for `weather`. Gson/Retrofit cannot automatically turn an array into a single Object, so you need to change your data class to hold a List (or use a custom Gson deserializer and manually grab the item you want from the array).

Example of what your top level class should be:

```
class WeatherData {
    var main: TemperatureData? = null
    var weather: List<WeatherDataJson>? = null
}
```

Comment: I did what you told me.I can now see the main value from json but i don't know how to get the other.Check my edited post

Comment: Is it possible to pass all the json data(main,weather,coord...) in data class TemperatureData so i can fetch them from there?